# Objective Memory Comparison

Tags: c++, memory, recursion, comparison

I would like to write an algorithm that compares one memory block with another and provides an objective value, so as to determine the quality of the match.  I've investigated `memcmp`, and all it is really useful for is to determine whether two memory blocks are identical or not.  I've written a recursive function to accomplish this, but it's not working quite right.

```
DWORD CMemory::Compare( LPBYTE pDst, LPBYTE pSrc, DWORD len )
{
    DWORD dwDiff;

    if ( len == 0 )
    {
        dwDiff = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        dwDiff = (*pSrc - *pDst) * len; // * len is attempt to weight difference by MSB
        dwDiff += this->Compare( pSrc + 1, pDst + 1, len - 1 );
    }

    return dwDiff;
}
```

The idea is that the more closely the two memory spaces match, the lower the return value will be.  For example, let's say there are three memory blocks containing `Hello World 0 !`, `Hello World 1 !`, and `Hello World 2 !`, respectively, and I would like to find out which memory block is a "best match" with candidate `hello world 1 !`.  The idea is that I would run the `Compare` function three times comparing the candidate with each memory block in turn, and `Compare` should return the lowest value for the memory block containing `Hello World 1 !`.  However, what it's doing in reality, is returning the lowest value for the last memory block containing `Hellow World 2 !`.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can improve this function?  Thanks.

Comment: Why not Hamming distance? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance

Comment: @c-smile: Thanks for the suggestion (+1)!  I re-wrote my algorithm to use Hamming distance, and it's working very well now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to take the absolute value of `(*pSrc - *pDst)`.  In "Hello World 1 !", you're getting a 0 for the number position, while in "Hello World 2 !" you're getting a -1, and -1 is less than 0.

Also, if you use this on a long section of memory you could run into stack problems, so you might want to make it iterative.

Your algorithm won't account for a character inserted or deleted, since it does a position by position compare.  If you're worried about that, the problem gets much harder.

Comment: +1, plus an extra moral point for mentioning that insertions and deletions will make this algorithm think the entire rest of the area is totally different. There are diff algorithms out there that try to compensate for this kind of thing, but it is tricky and easy to fool. If you've ever had a `diff` display get out of synch and start displaying stupid "diff"s, you know what I'm talking about.

Comment: "Hello World 1 !" and "hello world 1 !" are not equivalent.  That is, `'H' - 'h' != 0`.  However, you may be onto something with the absolute value.  The way my overall algorithm is currently structured the absolute value is determined from the final return value of `Compare`.  If I understand you correctly, I should be taking the absolute value of each and every difference, before it is added to the summation.

Comment: @Jim Fell:  However, the H difference is the same for "Hello World 1 !" and "Hello World 2 !", so there will be no comparative difference.  Yes, you should take the absolute value of each and every difference.

Answer (score 2):

Considered writing abs(*pSrc-*pDst)? As  otherwise you get negative values, which are allways lower than the perfect match (0).

Answer (score 1):

To improve this...

Supply a length for both the source and the destination.
Supply a value 'n', for comparing n bytes of the source and destination.
You need to handle the case when the source and destination aren't the same size, or you're going to have problems with walking off the end.

Don't use recursion, unless you're dealing with really small blocks of memory.
You can do the same work by just using a loop.
This method is really really expensive to call.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comparing strings, you may want to look into [soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex).

Comment: It's not necessarily strings.  I'm just using strings (`char[]`) to test this thing because they're easiest to enter and display from the console.  Once, this is working, it'll be comparing binary data.